# How to save reference to function before overriding it?

Tags: functions, plugin-system

I want to modify the behaviour of an existing plugin (without forking it), such that whenever a particular function `plugin_name#foo()` is called, my added behaviour is run afterwards. In some programming languages, an approach like this would work:

```
let g:Old_foo = funcref("plugin_name#foo")
function! plugin_name#foo() abort
  call g:Old_foo()
  echom "New, added behaviour"
endfunction
```

According to `:help funcref`, this should work:

```
funcref({name} [, {arglist}] [, {dict}])
        Just like |function()|, but the returned Funcref will lookup
        the function by reference, not by name.  This matters when the
        function {name} is redefined later.
```

And it does, so long as the old function and the new overriding function are defined in the same file named `plugin_name.vim`. I don't know why this might be. You can test it yourself by adding this to some `autoload/plugin_name.vim` file:

```
function! plugin_name#foo() abort
  echom "Old behaviour"
endfunction
```

When you do `:call plugin_name#foo()` you will just see "Old behaviour" printed. But after sourcing an additional `plugin_name.vim` file manually with the overriding snippet, that call gives infinite recursion and an error. When done from the vimrc the autoloaded function isn't even loaded yet, so it throws an error when trying to define the funcref.

Comment: This related question describes how to override script local functions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49447600/2144408. Presumably if my question is answered, the approach would work equally well for script local functions.

Comment: autoload function are a bit peculiar. It may be difficult to override them from a file not named `autoload/plugin_name.vim`. May be if you define your override in `after/autoload/plugin_name.vim`? (and test it hasn't already been overridden). (IIRC, I've mocked a few autoload functions, but never succeed in calling the original from the override)

Comment: `after/autoload/plugin_name.vim` doesn't even load automatically. Even to just override an autoloaded function, I have found I need to call it to make sure it gets loaded, and then define the function again.

Comment: Can you describe *precisely* what you're doing that results in infinite recursion in your question please? When your .vimrc is run, the autoload function hasn't been defined yet, so I'd expect the call to `funcref` to throw an `Unknown function` error, and that's what happens when I carry out the steps described currently in your question.

Comment: @Rich that's correct, the infinite recursion doesn't happen until after I source the script file manually and then call the function again. I did figure out how to do it, and posted my answer below - does that work for your use case as well?

Comment: @TamaMcGlinn I don't have a use case! I was going to attempt to explain what was broken in your original solution (I got the impression from your code you were mistaken about how autoload functions worked) and then come up with a solution. So I wanted to get to the same starting point as you. There's no need now you've solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's complicated. For example, if you want to add to the behaviour of `flog#floggraph#buf#Update()` you will need to create `flog/floggraph/buf.vim` with these contents:

```
if !exists("g:floggraph_navigate_update_override_defined")

  let g:floggraph_navigate_update_override_defined = v:true

  try
    call flog#floggraph#buf#Update()
  catch
    " ignore exception, this is just to force autoloading flog's buf.vim
  endtry

  let g:Floggraph_update_function = funcref("flog#floggraph#buf#Update")

  function! flog#floggraph#buf#Update() abort
    call g:Floggraph_update_function()
    echom "Update happened"
  endfunction

endif
```

and then source that from your new plugin or from your vimrc, like so:

```
let s:path = expand('<sfile>:h:h')
execute("source " .. s:path .. "/flog/floggraph/buf.vim")
```

In this case, since we have `/flog/` next to `/plugin/the_other_plugin.vim`, we need `:h` twice, once to get the dirname, and then one more to go up one directory to the root of the plugin repo.